# require.main.require works but not inside Mocha test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, path, mocha.js, require

I have written a global function for requiring certain files of my app/framework:

```
global.coRequireModel = function(name) {
    // CRASH happens here
    return require.main.require('./api/_co' + name + '/_co' + name + '.model');
}
```

This module is in /components/coGlobalFunctions.

It is required in my main app app.js like this:

```
require('./components/coGlobalFunctions');
```

Then in other modules using "something" from the framework I use:

```
var baseScheme = coRequireModel('Base');
```

This works but not in the Mocha tests which give me a "Error: Cannot find module" right before the require.main.require call.

It seems that the test is coming from another source folder. But I thought the require.main.require would take out the aspect of having to relatively linking to modules.

EDIT:

An example test file living in api/user:

```
var should = require('should');
var app = require('../../app');
var User = require('./user.model');
...
```

Comment: found a workaround for this? maybe to set module in tests?

Answer (score 7):

`require.main` points to the module that was run directly from node. So, if you run `node app.js`, then `require.main` will point to `app.js`. If, on the other hand, you ran it using `mocha`, then `require.main` will point to mocha. This is likely why your tests are failing.

See [the node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module) of more details.

Comment: What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 5):

Because require.main was not index.html in my node-webkit app when running mocha tests, it threw errors left and right about not being able to resolve modules. Hacky fix in my test-helper.js (required first thing in all tests) fixed it:

```
var path = require('path')
require.main.require = function (name) {
    // navigate to main directory
    var newPath = path.join(__dirname, '../', name)
    return require(newPath)
}
```

This feels wrong, though it worked. Is there a better way to fix this? It's like combining some of the above solutions with #7 to get mocha testing working, but modifying main's require just to make everything work when testing feels really wrong.

For other avoid-the-".."-mess solutions, see here:
https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but here is my solution.

I needed a test harness module to be published to a private registry and required by the mocha test suite.  I wanted the calling test code to pass the code under test to the harness rather than requiring it directly:

```
var harness = require('test-harness');
var codeUnderTest = harness('../myCode');
```

Inside harness (which was found in the project node_modules directory), I used the following code to make require find the correct file:

```
        if (!path.isAbsolute(target)) {
            target = path.join(path.dirname(module.parent.paths[0]), target);
        }
        var codeUndertest = require(target);
        ...
        return codeUnderTest;
```

This relies on the require path resolution that always starts with looking for a node_modules subdirectory relative to the calling file.  Couple that with module.parent and you can get access to that search path.  Then just remove the trailing node_modules part and concatenate the relative filename.

For other scenarios not using relative paths, this could be accomplished with the options parameter to require:

```
        var codeUndertest = require(target, {paths: module.parent.paths});
        ...
        return codeUnderTest;
```

And the two could be combined as well.  I used the first form because I was actually using proxyquire which does not offer the paths option.