# Detecting command line invocation with node.js and Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to find a way to detect if a file is instantiated from the command line or if it is required within a mocha unit test. Typically one does this with

```
if (require.main === module)
```

but I know that when using Mocha, the `require.module` is some `dir` within Mocha thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048108/require-main-require-works-but-not-inside-mocha-test).

Why I need it: I am writing unit tests and want the option of either

- including all files and running all tests at once in `index.js`
- or running an individual files tests at a time.

Here is the basic idea (in code) of what I want to do. Does anybody know how to tweak this code to get the functionality that I need?

index.js:

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

var displayErrors = require("./displayErrors");

describe("Running all tests now...", function () {
    displayErrors();
});
```

displayErrors:

```
"use strict";

var displayErrors = require("../../bin/displayErrors");

function test () {
    describe("Testing displayErrors.js now...", function () {
        it("blah", function (done) {
            displayErrors(function (status, statusText) {
                expect(1).to.equal(1);
                done();
            });
        });
        it("blah", function (done) {
            displayErrors(function (status, statusText) {
                expect(1).to.equal(1);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
}

module.exports = test;

if (require.main === module) {
    var chai = require('chai');
    var expect = chai.expect;

    test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mocha, you don't need your index.js. You can do this:

```
mocha // runs all tests
mocha -g blah // runs only tests with 'blah' in it or description
```